# Url Rewriting For Beginners

Tags: url, cakephp, url-rewriting, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I am new in the cakephp. I just learnt the cakephp 2.1 and just create a project. But I need some helps for my project. Lets say I create a forum and the setting for the forum. The name of the forum I can change from forum to anything. Let's say I change my forum name as in google. The original url is http://www.2hedesu.com/forum but I already change my forum as in google. supposed it should be http://www.2hedesu.com/google.

Can someone help me??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is explained here as nearly anything else:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html